# Why there are hearts around my Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I was playing sapphire today as usual but when I sent my zigzagoon to battle I noticed that there are hearts flown around him when it just came out of poke ball not the usual animations of lines or dots. Why is that?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different kinds of Poké Balls have different animations for when they pop open. In your case, I believe it's either a Nest Ball or a Luxury Ball.